# MDX result to JSON using C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, mdx

I'm new to MDX, basically I need to serialize the SSAS MDX result to a JSON object.

MDX Query:

```
SELECT
(
    [Measures].[Max Available]
) ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY 
(
    [Application].[Product].Children * [Application].[Application Name].Children
) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS
FROM [Applications]
```

Let's say I have a MDX result that looks like:

```
__________________________________
|          |          | Measure1 |
| Product1 | Feature1 | 1        |
| Product1 | Feature2 | 1        |
| Product1 | Feature3 | 10       |
| Product2 | Feature1 | 1        |
| Product2 | Feature2 | 1        |
| Product3 | Feature1 | 1        |
| Product3 | Feature2 | 1        |
| Product3 | Feature3 | 1        |
| Product3 | Feature4 | 1        |
```

I need to create a JSON object that looks like (I don't need the Measurement values, I just used them to get valid list of products and features in the MDX Heirarchy):

```
[
 {
   "product":"Product1",
   "feature":[
      "Feature1",
      "Feature2",
      "Feature3"
   ]
 }, {
   "product":"Product2",
   "feature":[
      "Feature1",
      "Feature2"
   ]
 }, {
   "product":"Product3",
   "feature":[
      "Feature1",
      "Feature2",
      "Feature3",
      "Feature4"
   ]
 }, {
   ...
 }
]
```

I use ADOMD.NET library using ExecuteCellSet(), but I'm also new to this one as well. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks,
dfox

Comment: I'm also stuck on the best approach to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not familiar with MDX, I have used JSON in C#. One way to create a JSON object (since they are not native in C# as of 4.5) is by using DataContracts.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Interface.Data
{
    [DataContract]
    class jsonObject
    {        
        [DataMember]
        public String product="";
        [DataMember]
        public String[] feature={"", "", ""};

        public jsonObject(){}
    }
}
```

Then in your MDX query, assuming you are storing the query data in some string 'line', you can do:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.IO;

static jsonObject json;
public static MDXObj parseMDXObj(String line)
{   
    MDXObj obj = new MDXObj(getMDX());
    try
    {     
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(jsonObject));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line));
        json = (jsonObject)ser.ReadObject(stream);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred in creating JSON: " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }
    return obj;
}
```